# Is there a way of getting the size of an array without finding it manually?

Tags: c++, arrays

So ive been making arrays this way but i found a error, lets say it was a loop that copied and array element by element:

```
int v1[] = { 3, 4, 7, 8};
int v2[sizeof(v1)];
for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(v2); ++i)
{
  v2[i] = v1[i]
}
```

The v2 array will not have the size of 4 integers, it adds them all up. So v2 would have the size of 22 not 4 integers. So i was wondering if there was any way of finding the size of an array without having to go to the array and see how many there elements there are manually. Is there a way? thanks.

Comment: Just change `sizeof(v1)` and `sizeof(v2)` to `sizeof(v1)/sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(v2)/sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(v1)/sizeof(v1[0])` and `sizeof(v2)/sizeof(v1[0])`

Comment: sizeof(v1) returns total byte size of memory under array, not count of int's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with the rest that you should use STL containers in general, in your case you can get the count of the elements in the array by using `sizeof(v1)/sizeof(int)`. `sizeof(v1)` will give you the total number of bytes for a 4 integer array and dividing by `sizeof(int)` will give you the number of elements.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting help.

Comment: Although I'd still recommend using ````std::array````, this piece of code can be slightly improved by using ````sizeof(v1)/sizeof(decltype(v1))````.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::array` or `std::vector`:

```
std::array<int, 4> v1 { 3, 4, 7, 8};
auto v2 = v1;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a9f271f15d608e)

Comment: Thank you, should i always prefer std::array over the c style array

Comment: @Harrythehacker When in doubt, yes. It's pretty much superior in any possible way.

Comment: In C++? Definitely, unless you are calling a C API that demands a C style array.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Even then you can use [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data).

Comment: @Harrythehacker Be sure to checkmark the answer that helped you most. ;)